# Какой выбрать метод в фреймворке Phalcon для реализации задачи?

Tags: php, highload, phalcon

Вопрос:
В фреймворке *Phalcon* я делаю сложный запрос через `phql`.
по типу:

```
$phql = 'SELECT ... JOIN ... WHERE ... LIMIT 0, 10';
```

Но всего записей в таблице `100,000` по параметрам в `WHERE`.
Итак запрос выполняю так:

```
$this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

В результате мне будет отображено `10` строк.

Но мне хочется узнать общее число строк.
Если использовать: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` - выведет ошибку.

Если использовать классы:

```
Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model
Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder
```

Но они не могут получить общее число строк без `LIMIT`
Вот кусок кода(почти из документации):

```
$builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder($phql);
$paginator = new \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder(array(
    "builder" => $builder,
    "limit"=> 5,
    "page" => 1
));
$page = $paginator->getPaginate();
print_r($page->total_pages());
```

Выведет 2, а не большое число.
Вообщем, хочется использовать методы *Phalcon*, а не делать 2 запроса или под-запросы.

Есть ли у кого-то опыт с таким делом? 
Прошу не предлогать выводить все через *PHP* и обработать, то это плохой вариант, так как это высоконагруженный проект.

Comment: в SQL же есть команда COUNT для подсчета строк в выборке. *Если использовать: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS - выведет ошибку.* - что за ошибка (и что за хайлоад такой)?

Comment: @Etki COUNT не подходит, так как нужно взять все строки. 
ORM делает из модели громадный массив и вот что выходит, при обращении к одной таблице с 50,000 строк:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/newcsfactor/public_html/apps/frontend/models/Users.php on line 1055

- что за ошибка (и что за хайлоад такой)?
не сильно понимаю зачем вы в вопросе скопировали эту строку: "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS - выведет ошибку."
3 запроса в секнду и больше до 100 где-то

Comment: COUNT вам выведет ровно одну строку. Три запроса в секунду (и сто тоже) - это не хайлоад.